# overwrite object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function A(){
   //how to alter persist to false here?
   B(obj.options);
}

function B(options){
   if(options.persist === true){ //do something }
}
```

I want to alter my nested object value. I can do it with one line, but what if I have many options's object? it's ugly I have to do it `obj.options.a`, `obj.options.b`, `obj.options.c` etc..

Comment: please add the data or part of the data as well.

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery extend function:

```
var object1 = { a: false, b: 1, c: 2 };
var object2 = { a: true, b: 2 };

jQuery.extend(object1 , object2 );
```

Comment: Yes, `jQuery.extend( [deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )` If true, the merge becomes recursive (aka. deep copy).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) - it is part of ES6 and [supported in most environments](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign) if you don't use a transpiler. The signature is quite similar to jQuery.extend:

```
Object.assign({}, object1, object2, { some: { nested: value }});
```

Or with ES6 you don't really need object assign, you can also write

```
const newObj = { ...oldObj, { keyToOverwrite: value }};
```